# Image does not show in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app which works just fine. Now, I want to display a static image as a logo on top of the page. Problem is the logo does not show up when I run the app, it just shows a missing file icon..

Top of my ui function looks like this:

```
    ui = fluidPage(
          img(heigth = 100, width = 100, src = "logo.png", align = "right"),

          pageWithSidebar(
            headerPanel(title = "ABC", windowTitle = "ABC"),
            sidebarPanel(...
```

I run the app as follows:

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Settings:

dir                       = "C:/app/";

folder_code               = "r/"; 

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main:

# Libraries:
library(shiny);
library(plotly);

# Includes:
source(file=paste(dir, folder_code, "analysis.r", sep=""));
source(file=paste(dir, folder_code, "plotlib.r", sep=""));
source(file=paste(dir, folder_code, "ui.r", sep=""));
source(file=paste(dir, folder_code, "server.r", sep=""));


# Run app:   
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options=list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

The directory where the app code and image is placed looks like this:

```
|r
  |www [<- my image is stored in this folder]
  analysis.r
  app.r
  ui.r
  server.r
  plotlib.r
```

EDIT:
With the following changes, it now works:

1. I create a file app.R with just this line of code:

   `app = shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`
2. In my main code displayed above, I replace

   shinyApp(...)

by

```
shinyAppFile(appFile = paste(dir, folder_code, "app.r", sep=""),
         options=list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

No clue however why it works like that and not as I had it previously..

Comment: have you tried: `img(heigth = 100, width = 100, src = "www/logo.png", align = "right")` ? Your ui.r is looking for logo.png in the same directory as it is, but the logo is in another folder (www)...

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but it doesn't help. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the permissions on your www directory and image- the directory should be drwxrwxr-x and image -rw-rw-r--.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but what exactly does "drwxrwxr-x" and "-rw-rw-r--" mean?

Comment: these are the permissions on your file and directory. If you open a terminal and navigate to the file loaction then type 'ls -l', the left hand column should show the permissions of these files. To change them simply type: chmod 664 filename; and chmod 775 directoryname    [see here for details](https://www.unixtutorial.org/2014/07/difference-between-chmod-and-chown/).